# javascript my function won't work the second time it's clicked

Tags: javascript, html

Hey guys I am still relatively new with JavaScript and need a bit of help. I tried a few different things and I can't seem to figure it out. I am having trouble with my commandHeld function. The first part of my function changes my class from "keyboard" or "keyboard_normal" to "keyboardCmd". I want the second part to change the class back to either "keyboard" or "keyboard_normal" based on what I have written in an h3 tag. I put the second part in another function I called regress and gave it a parameter of pressed because I plan to reuse it later.

The class changes to "keyboardCmd" just fine but When I click on my span again it doesn't change to "keyboard" or "keyboard_normal". I tried putting the code from regress () into commandHeld () instead of the regress function but no luck with the class changing from "keyboardCmd" to either "keyboard_normal" or "keyboard".

The "onclick" is on my cmdLeft and cmdRight Spans. I tried it with my cmdLeft_hover and cmdRight_hover spans as well just to be safe but that didn't help either.

***I published what I have so far on a temporary website. I hope this helps.
http://keyboard.businesscatalyst.com/index.html***

Here is my HTML:

```
    <body>
    <h3 id = "changeH3Text" onClick="changeNameToLetters()">Regular Keyboard on Hover</h3>
      <div id="keyboardContainer" class="keyboard">
      <div class = "row6">

             <span id="cmdLeft" onClick="commandHeld()">
             <span class="hover"  id="cmdLeft_hover"></span>
             </span>


              <span id="cmdRight" onClick="commandHeld()">
             <span class="hover"  id="cmdRight_hover"></span>
             </span>
      </div><!--end of row 6 div-->
   </div><!--end of keyboardContainer div-->
</body>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
function changeNameToLetters() {
    //keyboard container variables
    var keyboardState = document.getElementById("keyboardContainer");
    var currentClass = keyboardState.className;

    //h3 text variables
    var h3Text = document.getElementById("changeH3Text");
    var currentText = h3Text.innerHTML;

    if (currentClass == "keyboard_normal" && currentText == "Tool Name on Hover") {
        keyboardState.className = "keyboard";
        h3Text.innerHTML = "Regular Keyboard on Hover";
    } //end if
    else {
        keyboardState.className = "keyboard_normal";
        h3Text.innerHTML = "Tool Name on Hover";
    } //end else
} //End function

function commandHeld() {
    //keyboard container variables
    var keyboardState = document.getElementById("keyboardContainer");
    var currentClass = keyboardState.className;

    //h3 text variables
    var h3Text = document.getElementById("changeH3Text");
    var currentText = h3Text.innerHTML;

    if (currentClass == "keyboard_normal" || "keyboard") {
        keyboardState.className = "keyboardCmd";

    } //End if
    else {
        regress('keyboardCmd');
    }

} //End function

function regress(pressed) {
    //keyboard container variables
    var keyboardState = document.getElementById("keyboardContainer");
    var currentClass = keyboardState.className;

    //h3 text variables
    var h3Text = document.getElementById("changeH3Text");
    var currentText = h3Text.innerHTML;

    if (currentText == "Tool Name on Hover" && currentClass == pressed) {

        keyboardState.className = "keyboard_normal";

    } //End if
    else {
        keyboardstate.className = "keyboard";
    }
} //End Function
```

Comment: I tried to put this on http://jsfiddle.net/ but still can not understand what you try to archive. Could you provide a jsfiddle version of your code?

Comment: possibly an incorrect condition in this line `if (currentClass == "keyboard_normal" || "keyboard")`; also wondering if you've actually not used these comments `/*end of row 6 div*/`

Comment: @BangDao I tried putting it up on jsfiddle but the results weren't too great. http://jsfiddle.net/hothit43/9QJRc/6/

Comment: @BangDao published what I had so far on a temporary website I hope that helps http://keyboard.businesscatalyst.com/index.html

Comment: @Vishal I didn't actually use those comments. I noticed after I posted it that I used /* instead of <!-- but in the actual markup I use the proper format for comments. I don't know if it is that condition that is causing my issue. the class could be either one of those two before the function is executed. I published what I have so far to a temporary website I hope that this helps. Thank you. http://keyboard.businesscatalyst.com/index.html

Comment: It should be `currentClass == "keyboard_normal" || currentClass == "keyboard"`

Comment: @BangDao I tried doing that but I still get the same results. The first time I click on the span the function does what it is supposed to do and changes the keyboard container class name to keyboardCmd. Clicking on the span again when the class name is keyboardCmd produces no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little poking around with [Chrome console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) discovered that:

1. there's an invalid condition in your code (function `commandHeld`)
2. there's also a typo in the `regress` function (keyboardstate != keyboardState)

Working code:

```
function changeNameToLetters() {
    //keyboard container variables
    var keyboardState = document.getElementById("keyboardContainer");
    var currentClass = keyboardState.className;

    //h3 text variables
    var h3Text = document.getElementById("changeH3Text");
    var currentText = h3Text.innerHTML;

    if (currentClass == "keyboard_normal" && currentText == "Tool Name on Hover") {
        keyboardState.className = "keyboard";
        h3Text.innerHTML = "Regular Keyboard on Hover";
    } //end if
    else {
        keyboardState.className = "keyboard_normal";
        h3Text.innerHTML = "Tool Name on Hover";
    } //end else
} //End function

function commandHeld() {
    //keyboard container variables
    var keyboardState = document.getElementById("keyboardContainer");
    var currentClass = keyboardState.className;

    //h3 text variables
    var h3Text = document.getElementById("changeH3Text");
    var currentText = h3Text.innerHTML;

    if (currentClass == "keyboard_normal" || currentClass == "keyboard") {
        keyboardState.className = "keyboardCmd";

    } //End if
    else {
        regress('keyboardCmd');
    }

} //End function

function regress(pressed) {
    //keyboard container variables
    var keyboardState = document.getElementById("keyboardContainer");
    var currentClass = keyboardState.className;

    //h3 text variables
    var h3Text = document.getElementById("changeH3Text");
    var currentText = h3Text.innerHTML;

    if (currentText == "Tool Name on Hover" && currentClass == pressed) {

        keyboardState.className = "keyboard_normal";

    } //End if
    else {
        keyboardState.className = "keyboard";
    }
} //End Function
```

[Debugger](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging) is your friend :)

Comment: I'm loving the keyboard idea, by the way :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Works beautifully now :) The condition I tried changing it to that but it didn't change anything so I changed it back, I didn't realize it was invalid. I'll try and use the debugger in chrome more efficiently. Thank you so much Zathrus.